# Are Eaton BR breakers compatible with GE?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

We just underwent a home inspection, in which the breakers were flagged for having two different brands. I was told that Eaton is an off brand of GE, and that the breakers are compatible. Is there a website I can look this up, or can anyone help me? Thank you all si much in advance!

[image: Breakers]

Comment: Could you [edit] to get a sharper picture? The tiny text that's not quite readable may matter a lot here. Eaton makes classified replacement breakers for a number of panels. Whether that's the case here is unclear - if it's classified for another panel type, it's still alien in yours. But if it's classified for yours, it's legit. A picture of your panel's label would also be helpful.

Comment: I'll ask the seller for sharper pictures and panel, but what he said was it's a GE THQL 20 Amp 1 pole, and an Eaton BR220, type C220. Does Eaton have a document that shows whether it's classified? I've tried contacting them as well but no response. Thank you for help!

Comment: Looks like you got directed the right direction, but for your understanding the Eaton Classified products bear a different part number and UL symbol than the breaker shown in your picture. See image and compatibility list of Eaton CL breakers at https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/low-voltage-power-distribution-controls-systems/circuit-breakers/classified-circuit-breakers/ul-classified-replacement-circuit-breakers-sa00304001e.pdf . Also the electrical industry is awash with acquisitions, but Eaton and GE remain competing corporations.

Answer (score 3):

Eaton Type BR (for Bryant) are not compatible.
Eaton Type C (for Challenger) are not compatible.

At least, that's what we assume. The final word on the subject is on the panel labeling itself, where it lists all allowed breaker types.

I've seen real surprises there, so it might be worth checking.

---

Eaton Type CL (for Classified) *are compatible* despite not being mentioned on any label.  These are *UL-CLassified* for certain specific competitor panel lines, and overrides the label.  It's a specialty breaker that is available only at Eaton dealers. Normally THQL is cheaper, but it's rather useful for early GE panels that THQL breakers are not compatible with.

Comment: Thank you, I will go back to the seller with this information.

Comment: Note the correct breaker is $6.  I mention that because people often have no frame of reference for what stuff costs.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out - obviously, not something to hold up a house purchase. Thank you again!